# Implementation of Static and Global variables in C

Tags: c

Both Static and Global variables in C are stored in Data segment ( Uninitialized or Initialized ) but Static variable scope is only that file or that function and global variable scope is whole program and both variables life is whole program how it is implemented. They are stored in same segment even though how they different in behavior.

Comment: And what is the question? static vs global variables is related to their naming (and the scope of that name), and names don't matter at execution time (on Linux, you could `strip` the binary executable after compilation and linking).

Comment: There is also the difference between initialized (`data` segment) and uninitialized data (`bss` segment).

Comment: There is difference between initialized and uninitialized data segments but i need the implementation of static and global variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even both are in the data segement there is a difference ,`static` variables has `internal linkage` and `global` has `external linkage` (by default) that's why static is visible in the current translation unit but globals are visible in others.

By declaring variables static (which are in global scope), It means you are restricting the variable to the current file only.

Also initialzed and uninitialized variables are stroed in two different segement

[here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268) is the actual segmentation for every variables and code for a program.

```
C99 Standard : 6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers
```

2

In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
declaration of a particular identifier with `external linkage` denotes the same object or
function. Within `one translation unit`, each declaration of an identifier with `internal
linkage` denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identifier with `no
linkage` denotes a unique entity.

3

If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storageclass
specifier `static`, the identifier has `internal linkage`.22)

Comment: Please can you explain in more detail

Comment: given one link that will explain .. because drawing a figure here is tough